# changing the size of collectionView cell

Tags: swift, xcode, layout, uicollectionview, constraints

I'm not really good in maths so I want to change this vertical rectangle to be horizontal like in the image bellow small rectangle next to each other in one line I think there is a problem with the constraint

```
let areaView: UICollectionView = {
       let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
       let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cv.register(customCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cv.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 245, green: 245, blue: 245, a: 1)
       return cv
    }()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 245, green: 245, blue: 245, a: 1)
        view.addSubview(areaView)
        areaView.delegate = self
        areaView.dataSource = self
        setUpLayout()
    }


    func setUpLayout(){
        areaView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
        areaView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        areaView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        areaView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: areaView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true


    }
}

extension Search: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width/2.5, height: collectionView.frame.width/2)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! customCell
        cell.data = self.data[indexPath.row]
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        return cell
    }

}
```

[image]

to be like this one

[image]

and if I change the height for example to 50 it will be like this one

```
return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width/2.5, height: 50)
```

[image]

Comment: Try to use this inbuild functin collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize and adjust the height and width accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be providing wrong `height` in `sizeForItem`, try giving:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width/2.5, height: collectionView.frame.height/2)
}
```

Also, check out:
Change the `sizeForItem` method to adjust the size to what you require, like the following:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width/2.5, height: 50)
}
```

Here I'm giving it a height of 50 you can give whatever height you like.

You can also do this by adjusting your heightAnchor:

```swift
// areaView heightAnchor like this:-
areaView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

// and set sizeForItem to this :-

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width/2.5, height: collectionView.frame.height)
}
```

Comment: areaView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: areaView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true  this line effict the size

Comment: @mazenqp You need to update your height anchor too.

Comment: and if i want to chane the width to a constant shoul i do the same and give area width constraint too in setUpLaout Method

Comment: Yes, you'll have to give width to `sizeForItem`.

Comment: and constraint width should be?

Comment: You can give any constant you like.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214573/discussion-between-mazenqp-and-frankenstein).